# how to use a module in another module and route that in angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, module, angular8

How can I use a module in another module in angular 8? I would like create an application that use a modules in another module. is it possible? if yes how can I route from a link to this modules?

I build a menu module and inside that some components as menus. any menu refer to a new area that I want be a module. how can I do this?
the structure is:

```
menu(module)
      -first menu(component)
          an area(module)
              some components
              ...  
      -second menu(component)
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you will need to lazy load module

So what you need to do is

- Create a desire module you want to have in your app and include component you need
- Then add default route for that module
- Lazy load that module in your main app.routing.ts
- Add routeroutlet in your view to navigate to that route moudule

Comment: these modules are with same name at any sub-menu so I prefer to create the into the menu components. is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. But you need to import module to your main app-routing.ts using lazy load